# names and aliases using @Bean and @Component in spring

Tags: spring

How do we define

a) Single names
 b) Multiple names(aliases)

Using @Bean and @Component annotations ?

In XML we define like this:

For single name:

```
<bean name="accountService" autowire="constructor" class="com.wiley.beginningspring.ch2.AccountServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="false">
</bean>
```

For aliases:

```
<bean name="accountService,a,b" autowire="constructor" class="com.wiley.beginningspring.ch2.AccountServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="false">
</bean>
```

But what about @Bean and @Component( or @Service , @Repository ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is still a feature request https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6736

except for @Bean

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean(name = { "accountService", "acc" })
  public AccountServiceImpl cccountServiceImpl() {
    return new AccountServiceImpl();
  }

}
```

Comment: Q1)What about @Component ?  Q2) Does @Bean({"myid"}) creates a single id ?

Comment: for component this is yet to be implemented, @Bean({"myid"}) should created single instance

Comment: these are streo type markers except all create bean instances

Answer (score 1):

The bean name accepts array of Strings, so this works. `@Bean({"b1", "b2"}`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the name you can give to a bean from within the `@Component` (or one of its derivates) annotation you can give a single alias using `@Qualifier`:

```java
@Component("foo")
@Qualifier("bar")
public class OtherBean {

    public String doIt() {
        return "now";
    }
}
```

It's not possible to use several `@Qualifier` annotations.

Now you can reference to that bean both using "foo" as well as "bar".